# R dependend package seems not available in package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I can't figure out what I'm missing. Following Situation:

I wrote a R-Package lets call it "pkg_A"
It depends on "Rcpp" and I have a Module loaded and a class set up like :

```
Rcpp::loadModule("pkg_A_modul", what = "pkg_A_cppClass_A")
cppClass_A <- setRcppClass(
  Class = "pkg_A_cppClass_A",
  CppClass = "pkg_A_cppClass_A",
  module = "pkg_A_modul",
  fields = c(
     remark = "character"
  )
)
```

and a additional constructor

```
classA <- function(a,b){
  # some stuff
  tmpObj <- cppClass_A()
  # some more stuff
  return(tmpObj)
}
class(classA ) <- "classA "
```

The only Thing what I export to the NAMESPACE is the classA function/class.
That all works fine and I can build that package without any warnings and even can check it with "--as-cran" flag.

Now I want to build a second package on top of that package, lets call that "pkg_B" Therefore I list "pkg_A" in the DESCRIPTION Depends of "pkg_B"
as well as I load the class with `importFrom(pkg_A, classA)` in the NAMESPACE of "pkg_B".

Now I want to implement a class

```
classB  <- setRefClass(
  "classB",
  contains = c("classA"),
  fields = c( b = "numeric)
)
```

But when I now want to build "pkg_B" I get the error:

> Error in getClass(what, where = where) : "classA" is not a defined
>   class

I also tried to use the "pkg_A_cppClass_A" instead or imprt the whole pkg_A or use pkg_A::classA. Nothing changed.

Hope the question is complete enough. If you missing some info let me know.
Thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: I suspect it may be a visibility problem. Try a more globale `import: pkgA` rather than `importFrom`.  And also make sure `pkgB` has the (base R) package `methods` imported.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but importing the whole package by import pkgA made it work.